# Jquery mobile radio button alignment

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am facing a issue in the alignment of radio button. See the image for the issue. This is happening if i load the css from the local file system. But when I open the same page using a css pointing to an url its working properly.

The css I am using is 
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.min.css

The jquery viersion I am using is 1.9.1 and jqm version is 1.3.2. The source code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile">
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<base href=".">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<title>Mobile</title>

</head>
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport" >
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">

</div>
<div data-role="content">   

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right" id="choiceChooser">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-w-6" id="radio-choice-w-6a" value="Choice 1" >
        <label for="radio-choice-w-6a">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-w-6" id="radio-choice-w-6b" value="Choice 2">
        <label for="radio-choice-w-6b">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-w-6" id="radio-choice-w-6c" value="Choice 3">
        <label for="radio-choice-w-6c">Choice 3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-w-6" id="radio-choice-w-6d" value="Choice 4">
        <label for="radio-choice-w-6d">Choice 4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-w-6" id="radio-choice-w-6e" value="Choice 5">
        <label for="radio-choice-w-6e">Choice 5</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The fiddle for the same is

http://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/yFdgD/

[image]

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: @DKM: But the issue is happening when I load the css from local. Anyway I will update it after creating a fiddle

Comment: @DKM: Created the fiddle.

Comment: did u downloaded the css for local copy or copy pasted?

Comment: @Akki619: I downloaded the file from this url http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Replace the images file in local with the images which is bundled with jquery 1.3.2.

```
http://jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.zip
```

There is a conflict between the image files and position define in css file.

When you are using a css pointing to an url, the correct images are loaded.

Copy it and validate.